# Add drop down value for parameter in Crystal reports

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, business-objects

I'd like to add a value to the drop down for a parameter field to an exiting report. Can I do this through SAP BOXI interface? Or should I have to make the changes in crystal reports designer and publish the report again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any changes related to Parameters be it Dynamic or Static parameters, CR designer changes are required and then publishing the report again. You cannot do it through BOXI.

Following are a few tutorials links on how achieve that

[Create CR Parameters MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms227467(v=vs.80).aspx)

[Code Project Tutorial link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/205398/Crystal-Report-Filtering-Using-Selection-Parameter)